# 3-smooth number

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be the sequence of $3$-smooth numbers (that is whole number that can be written as $2^a3^b$ with $a,b\in\mathbb N$) sorted by increasing order. I am looking for the principal term of the asymptotic of $\log(u_n)$ as well as the error term, for $n\to+\infty$. Any idea to achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Closely related: the number of smooth numbers up to a given bound: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182775/how-to-give-a-solid-asymptotic-for-3-smooth-numbers

Comment: Related, yes, but does it give an answer to my problem?

Comment: You can deduce from there $\log u_n\sim\sqrt{2\log 2\log 3}\sqrt{n}$. If you figure out an error term for the number of smooth numbers, you can translate it to an error term to your problem.

Comment: How do you obtain this equivalent? I can not s the link between the number of $u_k$ lesser than $n$ and $u_n$.

Comment: @joaopa: Let $N(x)$ denote the number of $u_n$'s up to $x$. Then, according to the link above, $N(x)\sim(\log x)^2/(2\log 2\log 3)$. Hence $n=N(u_n)\sim(\log u_n)^2/(2\log 2\log 3)$, which gives $\log u_n\sim\sqrt{(2\log 2\log 3)n}$.

Answer (score 6):

3-smooth numbers are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A003586 and there you will also find the asymptotic, $${1\over\sqrt6}e^{\sqrt{2(\log2\log3)n}}$$ (attributed to Benoit Cloitre) as well as several links to the literature.

Comment: How do you obtain such an equivalent?

Comment: Have you gone to that webpage, joaopa, and followed the links given there?

Comment: I did not find a proof in the links on the oeis page.